# replace number of spaces inside EMPTY single quotation marks in notepad++ against same number of CHR(32)(2nd)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want replace **EVERY** space inside EMPTY single quotation marks against the **same number** of CHR(32).

> **condition:** REGEX has to match only this case - not for cases with signs between single quotation marks!
>
> **important hint:** the construct, where to replace the spaces between will begin in every case with:
>
> ```
> \|\|\s*'
> ```
>
> and ends (in every case) with (according to Row 1+2):
>
> ```
> '\s*\|\|
> ```

I use for search pattern:

```
'(\s)+'
```

and for replacement:

```
CHR\(32\)
```

But, this replaces all spaces against only **ONE** CHR(32)!

Following example:

```
vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || '    ' ||...;
vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || '' ||...;
(3)' WHERE   a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')  '   
(4) WHERE    a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')
```

my **incomplete** result:

```
vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || CHR(32) ||...;
vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || '' ||...;
(3)' WHERE   a.object_type IN (CHR(32)TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3WCHR(32))  '   
(4) WHERE    a.object_type IN (CHR(32)TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3WCHR(32))
```

**target result:**

```
vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || CHR(32) || CHR(32) || CHR(32) || CHR(32) ||...;
vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || '' ||...;
(3)' WHERE   a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')  '   
(4) WHERE    a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')
```

**Row 3 + 4 has to stay unchanged!**

*("(3)" and "(4)" are not part of this construct - were only used for explanation!) .*

This topic is caused as an alternative for:
[replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(4th)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347641/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)

**How can I define in notepad++ the replacement REGEX correct?**

Comment: is notepad++ supports `\G`?

Comment: If it were enough to just match quote separated by spaces this would work `\G(?!\A)(?<!')\s'?|'\s(?=\s*')'?`. However, it is not enough. Since you are matching to replace and you don't want to replace `''` you will eventually find something like this '`'   '`   ' as you can see, it will incorrectly match between quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [\G anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) to continue where the previous match ended. Something like this:

```
(?:'|\G(?!^))\s(?=\s*')'?
```

And replace with `CHR\(32\)`. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hN0xR7/1).

---

- `(?:` opens a non capture [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Matching literal `'` single quote `|` or:
- `\G(?!^)` continue where previous match ended. Without `(?!^)` \G would also match start.
- `\s` replaces a whitespace `(?=\s*')` [if followed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) by any amount of space and another `'`
- `'?` the ending `'` optional to maintain `\G` sequence.

[Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: your REGEX does not replace the single quotation marks. If I use this REGEX without \K - only the ending single quote 
will replaced, the opening (as you already wrote) not. Can you try to adjust your solution? Much thanks in advance!

Comment: @ora_job I've overlooked that! Please check [if it meet demands now](https://regex101.com/r/hN0xR7/1).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution (I adapted Jonny5's answer):

*(after I changed and extended this question, (sorry to Jonny5))*

search pattern:

```
(?:\|\|\s*'|\G(?!^))\s(?=\s*')'?
```

replacement pattern:

```
\|\| CHR\(32\)
```