# replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(4th)

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

In

[replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(2nd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037307/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)

"*Jonny 5*" solved this question - BUT - if I have a construct like this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN ('A' , 'st9u' ,'Meyer', ....);
WHERE    a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')
vpl_text := IS_GOING_SMALL_CORRECT

(1) vpl_text := TO_CHAR(vpl_text_old) || '    ' ||...;
-- ------
vpl_text := STAYS_UPPER_ERROR

(2) vpl_text := TO_CHAR(vpl_text_old) || '' ||...;
-- ------

vpl_text := IS_GOING_SMALL_CORRECT
```

then the target should be:

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name in ('A' , 'st9u' ,'Meyer', ....);
where    a.object_type in (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')
vpl_text := is_going_small_correct

(1) vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || '    ' ||...;
-- ------
vpl_text := stays_upper_error

(2) vpl_text := to_char(vpl_text_old) || '' ||...;
-- ------

vpl_text := is_going_small_correct
```

**but** the result is (The rest is **o.k.**!):

```
:
-- ------
vpl_text := STAYS_UPPER_ERROR

(2) vpl_text := TO_CHAR(vpl_text_old) || '' ||...;
-- ------
:
```

> **conditions:**  (same like in) 
>   [replace characters in notepad++ BUT exclude characters inside single quotation marks(2nd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037307/replace-characters-in-notepad-but-exclude-characters-inside-single-quotation-m)
>
> **It happens also, if I exchange the lines (1) and (2)!**

**How can I change this REGEX in notepad++ that ALL UPPER signs change to lower signs - exclude inside single quotation marks?**

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem with the previous regex is that `' '` was considered as an *opening* delimiter, and the whole text from `'     '` up to `''` was "protected" with the subroutine call.

Use

```
'\s*(?0)?(?=\w)[^']*'\K|(\w+)
```

The `(?=\w)` look-ahead makes sure that after the innermost starting `'` is followed by a word character. If there can be again a space, you may replace this look-ahead with `(?=\s*\w)`.

Comment: Much thanks for your effort - but - if I insert, direct behind (1), a construct like this 'WHERE  a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')  '
(single quotation marks at beginning (in front of WHERE)  and end (behind last right parenthesis)) then the problem stays the 
same (also if I replace this look-ahead with (?=\s*\w))   (This construct is not artificial - it appears in this kind in practice!)
(general it happens everywhere if I use this construct additional in this text) (without this construct, your solution runs brilliant!) Have you any solution?

Comment: Do you mean the string `'WHERE a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W' ') '`? It is all inside `'...'`. It should be left intact acc. to the requirements. Or not?

Comment: Much thanks for your effort - but - if I insert, direct behind **(1)**, a construct like this `'WHERE  a.object_type IN (' 'TABLE'', ''MATerialIZED VIE3W'   ')  '`
**(single quotation marks at beginning (in front of WHERE)  and end (behind last right parenthesis))** then the problem stays the 
same (also if I replace this look-ahead with (?=\s*\w))   (This construct is not artificial - it appears in this kind in practice!)
(general it happens everywhere if I use this construct additional in this text) (without this construct, your solution runs brilliant!) Have you any solution?

Comment: Try `'\K([^']*)(?='\s*'(?=\w)[^']*'\s*')|'\s*(?0)?(?=\w)[^']*'\K|(\w+)` with `\L\1\2` replacement.

Comment: Yes, I mean this string - during I tried to format the comment, our answers overlapped each other. (This string is the Problem!)

Comment: The Problem stays the same, exclude the **WHERE** and **IN**, inside this construct are lowered - that's not the target - all words inside **'...'** have to be **untoched**.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know what is wrong. Your current explanation is not clear: `' words ' 'SomeNames'' '` - what is inside `'...'`? What should be changed, what not?

Comment: I wrote **BEHIND (1)**, and meant direct after 1st `'-- -----'` (inacc. from my side, sorry) - then, as I wrote already, the problem stays the 
same, exclude the **WHERE.... (p1)** (p...problem).
In your updated answer it runs, exclude the **WHERE.... (p2)**.  If I move this statement to other positions, then we have (p1) or (p2). 
The REGEX has to be **independent of position of this construct**... (It may come many times and everywhere...)
(**'...'** ... means everything inside single quotation marks **(independent of number of nesting) has to be unchanged!)**

Comment: (additional comment) The maximal nesting of quotation marks is **3** !(as shown in this  construct)

Comment: I do not think it is solvable at all with regex then.